# Cakephp value from array

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I've read many similar topics here but not one helps me with problem.
i'm trying to get sections_id value from query in controller.

```
$query_id = "SELECT sections_id FROM sections WHERE name='".$table_name."'";
        debug($id = $this->Info->query($query_id)); die();
```

there is debug result

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'sections' => array(
        'sections_id' => '14'
    )
)
```

)

and i tried in controller get value of id typing **$id['sections']['sections_id']**, or
**$id['sections_id']** and many other types, nothing works. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I hope `$table_name` is escaped properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$id[0]['sections']['sections_id']` to access it

Answer (score 0):

For one result use

```
$data[0]['sections']['sections_id']
```

If query returns more than one result the use below code:

```
foreach($id as $data){
    echo  $data['sections']['sections_id']
}
```

Look for array index's carefully! Iinjoy